# Azure Datafactory Pipeline Failed inside a scheduled trigger

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-data-factory, azure-triggers

I have created 2 pipeline in Azure Datafactory. We have a custom activity created to run a python script  inside the pipeline.When the pipeline is executed manually it successfully run for n number of time.But i have created a scheduled trigger of an interval of 15 minutes in order to run the 2 pipelines.The first execution successfully runs but in the next interval i am getting the error "Operation on target PyScript failed: Hit unexpected exception and execution failed." we are blocked wiht this.any input on this would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

from [ADF troubleshooting guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/data-factory/data-factory-troubleshoot-guide#custom), it states...

**Custom Activity :**

The following table applies to Azure Batch.

**Error code**: 2500

**Message**: Hit unexpected exception and execution failed.

**Cause**: Can't launch command, or the program returned an error code.

**Recommendation**: Ensure that the executable file exists. If the program started, make sure stdout.txt and stderr.txt were uploaded to the storage account. It's a good practice to emit copious logs in your code for debugging.

**Related helpful doc**: [Tutorial: Run Python scripts through Azure Data Factory using Azure Batch](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/batch/tutorial-run-python-batch-azure-data-factory)

Hope this helps.

If you are still blocked, please share failed pipeline run ID & failed activity run ID, for further analysis.